# With R and XML package how do I scrape a HTML table that includes a specific text?

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to scrape a website to grab and put into a data frame a specific html table.

[Web Site](http://www.advfn.com/stock-market/NYSE/LF/financials?btn=start_date&start_date=13&mode=annual_reports)

For example, I want just the entire table that includes the word "EBIT". I messed around with getting all the tables with XML:

```
library(XML)
theurl <- "http://www.advfn.com/stock-market/NYSE/LF/financials?btn=start_date&start_date=13&mode=annual_reports"
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)

summary(tables)
```

I am new to web scraping and could use some help. Thanks in advance

Aaron

Comment: `tables[[2]]`, `tables[[6]]` and `tables[[7]]` each contain EBIT.

Comment: Hmm, EBIT was a bad example then, maybe it would help if I told you my end goal.. I want to be able to scrape and get the entire financial statement into a data.frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close to what you want:

```
library(rvest)
stock <- read_html("http://www.advfn.com/stock-market/NYSE/LF/financials?btn=start_date&start_date=13&mode=annual_reports")

stock %>% 
  html_nodes(".sb") %>% 
  html_text()
```

Comment: that's close, but would like to get the entire financial statement and ratios ect.

Comment: What is the significance of ",sb"? Also how to I convert this to a data.frame?

Comment: This is a good resource: http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/. To convert to a data frame you could add `%>% as.data.frame()`in the end of the code above.